# filter xml nodes in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I got a xml like this:

```
    <row1>
  <name />
  <data>
     <content>Oct - Dec 13</content>
     <content>Jan - Mar 14</content>
     <content>Apr - Jun 14</content>
     <content>Jul - Sep 14</content>
     <content>Oct - Dec 14</content>
     <content>0##8##</content>
     <content>0##9##</content>
  </data>
    </row1>
```

I want to filter the node and then push in the array, for example, i just want the node without "##",and then push the  elements into a array.

Here is the code i edit, but no lucks

```
 $xml.find('row1 content').each(function(i, content) {

                if ('content:contains("0")'){
                $(this).text("1");

                }
                else{
                options.xAxis.categories.push($(content).text());
                }
            });
```

Could anyone tell me where is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $xml.find('row121 content').each(function(i, content) {

                if ($(content).text() == "0##8##"||$(content).text() == "0##9##"){
                $(this).text("null");

                }

                else{
                options.xAxis.categories.push($(content).text());
                }
            });
```

use condition|| it could solve the problem